# Prove $\{ (x,y) \in [0,1]^2: x-y\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $T:=\{ (x,y) \in [0,1]^2\ :\ x-y\in \mathbb{Q} \}$. Show that $T$ has measure zero, but it meets every set of the form $A \times B$ , where $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets of positive measure in $[0,1]$.

T is measurable since it will be countable union of lines in $[0,1]^2$ and thus will be of measure zero, but why does it intersect every $A \times B$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A^{\sharp}=\bigcup_{q\in{\mathbb Q}}(A+q)\cap [0,1]$. Then $A^{\sharp}$ is measurable, and by this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231719/measure-of-a-set-invariant-by-rational-translation/1232447#1232447) $\mu(A^{\sharp})$ is
either $0$ or $1$. But $A\subseteq A^{\sharp}$ (take $q=0$), so we must have $\mu(A^{\sharp})=1$. It follows that $\mu(A^{\sharp}\cap B)=\mu(B)$ ;
in particular $A^{\sharp}\cap B$ is nonempty. Let $b$ be an element of this nonempty set. Then $b\in B$, and since $b\in A^{\sharp}$ we must have
an $a\in A$ and a $q\in {\mathbb Q}$ such that $b=a+q$. Then $(a,b)\in (A\times B) \cap T$.