# measure of a set invariant by rational translation

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Say that a measurable subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ is ${\mathbb Q}$-stable
if $a+q\in A$ whenever $a\in A,q\in{\mathbb Q}$ and $a+q\in [0,1]$.
Obviously, $\emptyset$ is ${\mathbb Q}$-stable and has measure zero,
and $[0,1]$ is ${\mathbb Q}$-stable and has measure one.
Are there ${\mathbb Q}$-stable subsets with measure other
than $0$ or $1$ ?

EDIT : Let $A$ be ${\mathbb Q}$-stable. It is easy to see that
if $[a,b[$ and $[c,d[$ are two subintervals of $[0,1]$ with
rational endpoints and with the same length ($d-c=b-a$), then
$A\cap [c,d[=(c-a)+A\cap [a,b[$ whence $\mu(A\cap [c,d[)=
\mu(A\cap [a,b[)$. It follows that
there is a function $\alpha : [0,1] \to {\mathbb R}_{+}$ 
such that $\mu(A\cap [a,b[)=\alpha(b-a)$ for any rational $a<b$ in
$[0,1]$. The map $\alpha$ is obviously nondecreasing. Also,
if $x,y \in {\mathbb Q}$ are nonnnegative with $x+y\leq 1$ then
$(A\cap [0,x+y[)$ is the disjoint union of 
$(A\cap [0,x[)$ and $(A\cap [x,x+y[)$, and hence 
$\alpha(x+y)=\alpha(x)+\alpha(y)$.

It follows that there is a constant $c$ such that
$\alpha(t)=ct$ for any $t\in{\mathbb Q}\cap [0,1[$. By monotonicity
the inequality stays true if we take $t\in [0,1[$. Not sure about 
how to finish from here.

Comment: Is your sum : "sum mod  1" ?

Comment: @FardadPouran No, there's no mod 1. Only intersection with $[0,1]$. The set $A$ is free to do anything it wishes outside $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my own question. By what is shown in the edit, the density of $A$ is equal to $c$ (or does not exist) at every point. But according to the [Lebesgue density theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem), if $\mu(A)>0$
then this density exists and is equal to $1$ a.e. This forces $c=1$ and $\mu(A)=1$.